# Given a list of strings, remove an item from list of dicts based on its value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following list of dicts:

```py
money_line = [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "book": "SPORT_888"
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "book": "WYNN"
            },
            {
              "id": 3,
              "book": "BET_RIVERS_VA"
            },
            {
              "id": 4,
              "book": "WILLIAM_HILL"
            {
              "id": 5,
              "book": "SUGAR_HOUSE_NJ"
            },
            {
              "id": 6,
              "book": "WYNN_NY"
            }
]
```

And the following list of strings:

```py
list_to_remove = ["SPORT_888", "WYNN", "MGM"]
```

As you can see, in the dict values I have a suffix on "WYNN_NY" items. I need to remove from money_line all items that are in list_to_remove, ignoring the suffix.

Already tried:

```
live_money_line = [i for i in money_line if i['book'].rsplit('_', 1)[0] not in list_to_remove]
```

But that would remove "888" "SPORT_888", and that's not the result I need.

Also tried:

```py
for code in list_to_remove:
  for item in money_line:
    if code in item['book']:
      money_line.remove(item)
```

But for some reason it's not working properly. It keeps wrong items on the money_line list.

Am I missing something in this for loop, or is there a better way to make this work?

Desired result:

```py
money_line = [
            {
              "id": 3,
              "book": "BET_RIVERS_VA"
            },
            {
              "id": 4,
              "book": "WILLIAM_HILL"
            {
              "id": 5,
              "book": "SUGAR_HOUSE_NJ"
            }
]
```

Comment: Hey, when I ran your code, "SPORT_888" was not left out from the resultant list

Comment: Your first code example gives me four dicts for item ids 1, 4, 5, 6. That seems correct to me.

Comment: Okay, I edited my examples to fit my needs. Now will make more sense

Comment: @C.S.F.Junior So you want to keep the 'NY' part in 'WYNN_NY'?

Comment: Yes, I need to keep it. I need to compare like "WYNN" in "WYNN_NY" like the for loop. But for some reason is not working properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `startswith()` and `any()` together to filter out the dictionaries you don't want:

```
money_line = [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "book": "SPORT_888"
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "book": "WYNN"
            },
            {
              "id": 3,
              "book": "BET_RIVERS_VA"
            },
            {
              "id": 4,
              "book": "WILLIAM_HILL"
            },
            {
              "id": 5,
              "book": "SUGAR_HOUSE_NJ"
            },
            {
              "id": 6,
              "book": "WYNN_NY"
            }
]


list_to_remove = ["SPORT_888", "WYNN", "MGM"]

[d for d in money_line if not any(d['book'].startswith(token) for token in list_to_remove)]
```

Which results in:

```
[{'id': 3, 'book': 'BET_RIVERS_VA'},
 {'id': 4, 'book': 'WILLIAM_HILL'},
 {'id': 5, 'book': 'SUGAR_HOUSE_NJ'}]
```

Comment: Most importantly, this uses a *list comprehension* to create a *new list* containing the dictionaries they want, instead of trying to remove the dictionaries they don't want from the original list.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer the comprehension (new list of dicts):

```
d = [d for d in money_line if not any(d['book'].startswith(prefix) for prefix in list_to_remove)]
```

If you prefer the loop with remove (in-place):

```
for i in reversed([i for i, d in enumerate(money_line) 
                   if any(d['book'].startswith(prefix) for prefix in list_to_remove)]):
    del money_line[i]
```